# SQL Server grouped rows return with default values if no row available for a date period

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a stored procedure which groups up rows based on their month and return a sum of all items if they exist and 0 if they don't.

For the date part of the query, what I am trying to get is today's date - extract the month and go back 5 months to gather any data if it exists.

At this stage, the query runs fine as is but I'm wondering if there's any way to optimise this as it looks like I'm running the same set of data over and over again and also it's hard coded to an extent.

The dataset I am trying to achieve is as follows:

```
Month    TotalAmount    TotalCount
-----------------------------------
2017-11  0              0
2017-12  200.00         2
2018-01  300.00         3
2018-02  0              0
2018-03  300.00         3
2018-04  100.00         1
```

Using the following query below, I was able to achieve what I want but as you can see, it's hard coding back the past 5 months so if I wanted to go back 12 months, I'd have to add in more code.

```
DECLARE @5MonthAgo date = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETDATE()) + 1 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETDATE())) AS DATE)
DECLARE @4MonthAgo date = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE()) + 1 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE())) AS DATE)
DECLARE @3MonthAgo date = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE()) + 1 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())) AS DATE)
DECLARE @2MonthAgo date = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE()) + 1 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE())) AS DATE)
DECLARE @1MonthAgo date = CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) + 1 - DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())) AS DATE)
DECLARE @CurrentMonth date = CAST(GETDATE() + 1 - DATEPART(DAY, GETDATE()) AS DATE)

-- Table to return grouped and sum data
DECLARE @StatsTable TABLE ([Month] DATE, 
                           [Total Amount] DECIMAL(18,2),
                           [Total Count] INT
                          )

-- Temporary table to hold onto data batch - so table isn't used later on
DECLARE @TempGenTable TABLE ([Id] INT,
                             [Date] DATETIME,
                             [Lines] INT NULL,
                             [Amount] DECIMAL(18, 2) NULL
                            )

INSERT INTO @TempGenTable
    SELECT
        Id, Date, Lines, Amount
    FROM 
        TallyTable
    WHERE 
        Date >= @5MonthAgo

INSERT INTO @StatsTable
    SELECT
        @5MonthAgo,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Amount)
                  FROM @TempGenTable
                  WHERE Date >= @5MonthAgo AND Date < @4MonthAgo
                  GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Date), 0)), 0),
        COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(Id)
                  FROM @TempGenTable
                  WHERE Date >= @5MonthAgo AND Date < @4MonthAgo
                  GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Date), 0)), 0)

    UNION

    SELECT
        @4MonthAgo,
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(Amount)
                  FROM @TempGenTable
                  WHERE Date >= @4MonthAgo AND Date < @3MonthAgo
                  GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Date), 0)), 0),
        COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(Id)
                  FROM @TempGenTable
                  WHERE Date >= @4MonthAgo AND Date < @3MonthAgo
                  GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Date), 0)), 0)
     ...
```

Is there an easier way to be able to get the above data with more flexibility in the number of months?

Is it better to just have the query pass in a month variable and it checks just the current month and have a loop within the controller to go back x number of months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generate the data using a recursive CTE and then use `left join`:

```
with months as (
      select datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1) as month_start, 5 as n
      union all
      select dateadd(month, -1, month_start), n - 1
      from months
      where n > 0
     )
select m.month_start, count(s.id), sum(s.amount)
from months m left join
     @StatsTable s
     on m.month_start = s.month
group by m.month_start
order by m.month_start;
```

You haven't provided sample data, so I'm not sure what `s.month` looks like.  You might want the join condition to be:

```
on s.month >= m.month_start and s.month < dateadd(month, 1, m.month_start)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example Gordon, i'm having a bit of trouble following this example though as i'm getting compilation errors.
I'm assuming that the 'mon_start' at the first datefromparts is meant to be 'month_start' as doing that removes the first error. However, i'm getting compilation errors from the "UNION ALL" section where it's doing a dateadd on 'mon_start' (doesn't know what mon_start is) and also doesn't know what 'n' and 'dates' are from.
Are you able to elaborate on what these values should be from or if they're dynamic variables that are being created?

Comment: @intrepidexplorer . . . I had the wrong table name in the recursive part, `dates` instead of `months`.

Comment: Ah i see, thanks for the update, i've got the query to run now after changing that, one more minor thing is that the 'mon_start' on the top needs to be 'month_start' as it looks like we're using the variable 'month_start' in the select query below.
So the recursive CTE is the [with months as...] section and is like a foreach loop i'm guessing? It looks like what I was wanting on my initial query with the 'hard coding' of the months with unions except it's programmatically done for you within the "with" section. Will keep this in mind when performing any other loops.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a set-based method to generate the needed monthly periods:

```
--sample data
CREATE TABLE dbo.TallyTable (
      Id int
    , Date datetime
    , Lines int 
    , Amount decimal(18, 2)
    );
INSERT INTO dbo.TallyTable
VALUES
     (1, '2017-12-05', 1, 50.00)
    ,(2, '2017-12-06', 1, 150.00)
    ,(3, '2018-01-10', 1, 100.00)
    ,(4, '2018-01-11', 1, 100.00)
    ,(5, '2018-01-12', 1, 100.00)
    ,(6, '2018-03-15', 1, 225.00)
    ,(7, '2018-03-15', 1, 25.00)
    ,(8, '2018-03-15', 1, 50.00)
    ,(9, '2018-04-20', 1, 100.00);
GO

DECLARE @Months int = 5; --number of historical months
WITH
     t10 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t100 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1 AS num FROM t10 AS a CROSS JOIN t10 AS b)
    , periods AS (SELECT
              CONVERT(varchar(7), DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '', GETDATE()) - num, ''),121) AS Month
            , DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '', CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) - num, '') AS PeriodStart
            , DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, '', CAST(GETDATE() AS date)) - num + 1, '') AS NextPeriodStart
        FROM t100
        WHERE num <= @Months
    )
SELECT periods.Month, COALESCE(SUM(Amount), 0) AS TotalAmount, COALESCE(COUNT(ID), 0) AS TotalCount
FROM periods
LEFT JOIN dbo.TallyTable ON
    TallyTable.Date >= PeriodStart
    AND TallyTable.Date < NextPeriodStart
GROUP BY periods.Month
ORDER BY periods.Month;
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive guide Dan, very helpful. I ran into a problem where dates with no data weren't showing up but managed to fix it by putting them in the JOIN clause instead of adding it inside the WHERE clause.
Just wondering, where can I read more about what you did on t10? I'm curious to know what the select n from values (0)s all mean and why there are 10 (0)s in that select?

Comment: The `t10` CTE uses [row constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) to return 10 rows. The actual value of each row (zero) doesn't matter in here since the column is not referenced. The resultant 10 rows are used to generate the 100 rows and the `ROW_NUMBER()` used in the interval calculation.